# Jenkins double ssh only do the fist ssh step and doesn't do all the things asked

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh, ksh

I am currently building a big jenkins job, and I need, in the same stage and step to do multiple ssh as showed in the code below. The problem is that everytime jekins finishes the first ssh connection, it ends the stage, and the other parts are not ran.

Does anyone have the solution?

Here is my stage code:

```
stage('(02) Export file') {
            withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: gitCredentials, gitToolName: 'Default')]) {
                    sh '''
                        ssh user@env << EOF
                            mkdir /alim1 || true
                            mkdir /alim2 || true
                            mkdir /alim3 || true
                        << EOF

                        scp script1.ksh user@env:/alim1
                        scp script2.ksh user@env:/alim2
                        scp script3.ksh user@env:/alim3
                            
                        ssh user@env << EOF
                            echo "Starting export"
                            ksh /alim1/script1 || error1=1
                            ksh /alim2/script2 || error2=1
                            ksh /alim3/script3 || error3=1 
                        << EOF;
                    '''
            }
}
```

EDIT:
I changed the here-docs end, it now look like that:

```
stage('(02) Export file') {
            withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: gitCredentials, gitToolName: 'Default')]) {
                    sh '''
                       ssh user@env << EOF 
                           mkdir /alim1 || true; 
                           mkdir /alim2 || true; 
                           mkdir /alim3 || true; 
                       EOF

                       scp script1.ksh user@env:/alim1
                       scp script2.ksh user@env:/alim2
                       scp script3.ksh user@env:/alim3

                       ssh user@env << EOF
                           echo "Starting export"
                           ksh /alim1/script1 || error1=1;
                           ksh /alim2/script2 || error2=1;
                           ksh /alim3/script3 || error3=1;
                       EOF
                       '''
            }
}
```

I get this error:
`-ksh[11]: EOF: not found [No such file or directory of this type]`

Comment: I don't see the ending `EOF` for the starting here-docs. Don't you get any error message?

Comment: you mean the ";" after the EOF ?

Comment: Not only the semicolon. A here document is terminated by a line, which has the here-identifier `EOF` starting in column 1. There is no such line.

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. We can't see any line endings. Edit your question to post your new code. There is a small edit button just below your question.

Comment: BTW, what is the point of `|| true` in i.e. `mkdir /alim1 || true`? If you only need a zero exitcode, you can write it easier as `mkdir -p /alim{1..3}`.  But unless your remote shell is doing a `set -e`, I don't see why you should worry about the `mkdir` exit code.

Comment: This is a simplified code of my problem. the directories created are not with the same name, it was just to show I am creating multiple dir. But yeah, I could probably delete the `|| true`

Comment: You didn't show the complete, updated Jenkins stage. As you see, the error message comes from ksh now, while the code you posted shows only the mkdir part.

Comment: In fact, I didn't posted it because I know it doesn't go as far as the end of the first here-document. I didn't said it before, but I have an `echo "Starting Export";` in the first line of my second here-document, and this one doesn't even trigger. + the scp give me errors because the program thinks it is inside the here-document.

Comment: The Groovy part is missing. We need to see everything from `stage` up to the final `}`.

Comment: Aside from this, you still forgot to remove the semicolon after the `EOF`.

Comment: BTW, you would have less trouble fixing this problem, if - instead to write anything into a Groovy `sh` call explicitly - would create a standalone shell script, which is doing all the ssh and scp stuff, and invoke this script from your Jenkins task.

Comment: I just did what you said, and I get the same error. I know that doing a standalone script would be easier, but I want to have the stage part visible on Jenkins, that unable it. Maybe I should create for of this scripts and ask jenkins to execute them from the stages ?

Comment: Of course you get the same error: EOF must be the only text in its line. You have plenty of spaces to its left, and at lest one semicolon to its right.

Comment: Please get yourself familiar with [here-docs](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: You are right, deleting all the spaces on the left corrected the problem. I will post it as the answer. Thank you for your help and advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the problem was quite simple. I lacked knowledge about here-document and I didn't know that EOF needed to be the only caracters on the line, there shouldn't be any indentation. The working/corrected code is this one:

```
stage('(02) Export file') {
            withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: gitCredentials, gitToolName: 'Default')]) {
                    sh '''
                       ssh user@env << EOF 
                           mkdir /alim1 || true; 
                           mkdir /alim2 || true; 
                           mkdir /alim3 || true; 
EOF

                       scp script1.ksh user@env:/alim1
                       scp script2.ksh user@env:/alim2
                       scp script3.ksh user@env:/alim3

                       ssh user@env << EOF
                           echo "Starting export"
                           ksh /alim1/script1 || error1=1;
                           ksh /alim2/script2 || error2=1;
                           ksh /alim3/script3 || error3=1;
EOF
                       '''
            }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your aesthetical requirements, you could have kept the EOF aligned below the `ssh`, and instead apply `stripIndent` to your whole Groovy string. This is described [here, in chapter 4.2](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-strings).